# How to minimize iframe vertical space with CSS?

Tags: html, css, iframe

For some reason, iframes seem to consistently use more vertical space than they need. This is demonstrated by the following repl: https://repl.it/@sparkleponythe/MoralOutlandishAdministration

[image: unnecessary space]

Is there some way to tell an iframe to minimize the vertical space it requires, preferably without JS? In the example repl, I've tried to minimize space by setting the margin, padding, and border of `html`, `body`, and `iframe` to 0, but it did not minimize the vertical space of the iframe. I should mention that I can control the CSS both inside and outside of the iframe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of an iframe is not affected by anything inside the iframe, and setting CSS rules in the parent will not affect the contents of the framed child window. In other words:  the parent controls the frame size, border, and margin outside the frame boundaries, the child controls the contents of the frame (including the body margin and padding inside the frame boundaries.)

The default height of an iframe is about 150px, but it can be sized (by the parent window) as any block-level element:

```css
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
text text text
<iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>
text text text
```